# Is it possible to port GNU grep as a library?

Tags: c, grep, gnu

I would like to know if it is possible to port **GNU grep** as a libary, leaving aside the legal complications, if any, as this is purely for non-commercial, but academic use. I have seen many ports exist of GNU grep. For example : GNU grep for win 32 [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm).

I wonder why nobody has ever attempted to port grep as a library ? It would be a huge benefit to applications that exploit string searching/mining as they can use the power of GNU grep internally in the their applications. I would like to attempt this feat, but since I am new to string searching/mining, would love to know the obvious challenges that may arise and why it has not been done as yet.

EDIT - The advantage of a GNU grep library is that it will do string searching much faster, using its own modified version of boyer-moore. Where as when using a regular expression wrapper library such as PCRE or Boost reg exp or Qt Reg expressions etc, **the application has to read the file line-by-line and parse each line** against the regexp. This is the obvious advantage that I see.

Comment: It's not *exactly* the same, but have you considered the [PCRE library](http://www.pcre.org/) instead?

Comment: To make grep's interface available as lib you do not need to dive deeply into its internals. Mainly you need to understand how it builds and how the command line options are mapped to the specific functions. Having done so its just a matter of writing some wrappers and managing the process of building a library in general. Go ahead and give it a try: ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/grep/

Comment: @AdamRosenfield, it is definitely not what I want - see the update. Thanks, alk this is what I want, i hope it is doable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Just link it as a library and call its main() with its intended arguments. Or better if you rename its main() to some better, f.e. to grep().

Comment: I will wager grep's main() is not reentrant - i.e. not so fun things will happen when you call it more than once - having lots of state from the previous run.

Comment: You have right, altough I think these problems could be probably solved with the conversion of its global variables to local. And if grep does an exit(), it were a problem, too. And if grep doesn't free()-s all of its malloced memory, then this library will leak. But this problems can be solved and doesn't seem very hard, altough a little bit of playing with the grep source code seems to be unavoidable.